# operator overloading self assignment

Tags: c++

can anyone please explain the below function.

```
  AddressBook& operator =(const AddressBook& bok);///add this two to your struct
    bool operator ==(const AddressBook& bok);///

/***************************************************************************************/
    ///anywhere outside main add this definitions

    bool AddressBook::operator ==(const AddressBook& bok)
    {
        return (firstname==bok.firstname&&lastname==bok.lastname&&addr==bok.addr&&phone==bok.phone);
    }

    AddressBook& AddressBook::operator=(const AddressBook& bok)
    {
        if(*this==bok)
            return *this;
        else
        {
            firstname=bok.firstname;
            lastname=bok.lastname;
            addr=bok.addr;
            phone=bok.phone;
        }
         return *this;
    }
```

Comment: What about it do you not understand? Ask a specific question.

Comment: You should perhaps read up about several aspects of C++, e.g. overloaded operators. The one with name `==` is an overloaded equality operator for the AddressBook class, and the other one is an overloaded assignment operator for that class.

Comment: What exactly do you want to know? What is your actual question?

Comment: I guess the question is: "what is this"? I assume overloaded operators are new to him.

Comment: i just wanted to know         AddressBook& AddressBook::operator=(const AddressBook& bok)
    {
        if(*this==bok)
            return *this;
        else
        {
            firstname=bok.firstname;
            lastname=bok.lastname;
            addr=bok.addr;
            phone=bok.phone;
        }
         return *this;
    } this particular step. how it goes

Comment: @Sachin: this is something any good textbook teaching C++ will handle. I suggest you get such a book.

Comment: you have to be precise aobut what you dont understand. Reading your title one can get the impression you know what self assignment means in the context of the assignment operator, however it seems your question is actually "What is the meaning of self assignment in the context of assignment operator?" ;)

Answer (score 1):

There are two functions here. Both of them overloading [operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators).
The comparison operator for equality `operator==` will in this case compare two objects of type `AddressBook`. It will return `true` (saying two addressbook objects are equal) when they match in `firstname`, `lastname`, `addr` and `phone`.
The assignment operator will allow you to assign an `AddressBook` object to another, and it will copy over the values.

```
if (*this = bok)
    return *this;
```

in this case checks if you assign an object to itself. In a class [`this`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/this) pointy to the instance of the object. In this case the left hand side of the `=` operator. If they are the same (Meaning their address in memory is the same), then nothing is copied.
The `=` operator returns the value assigned. That is why things like

```
a = b = 7;
```

are valid. `b = 7` assigns 7 to b. The operator returns the value 7. Then that return of 7 is assigned to a. The return value of that operation is discarded.
It is also the unfortunate reason why things like

```
int a = 5, b = 7;
if(a = b) // assignment, not comparison!
{ /*Do things*/ }
```

are valid. `a` is assigned the value of `b`, the return of the assignment-operation (the value of `b`, 7) is then used as the condition, which evaluates true. Even if you do want such a thing, it is bad style and should be written in two lines.
All operators in c and c++ are function calls.

Comment: @SachinKGowda thats for `a = a;` then `this` points to the left hand side and the operator does not have to copy anything

Comment: @SachinKGowda if Mystr2 is an instance of a class that is not `String`, this would require overloading and would be possible, yes.

Comment: @FalcoGer yes you're right its a instance of a class. can i overload the same like Mystring& operator =(const char &c[20]).  i have already overloaded = in same program like Mystring& operator =(const Mystring & ms);

Comment: @SachinKGowda I recommend reading up on operator overloading.

Comment: @FalcoGer thanks for your suggestion. i have  a situation. Mystring str4; i want to calculate str4.length(). in what way i could get it solved